# git config not recognised

Tags: python, git, config, conda

I can't run Pyscaffold putup because, it tells me, my git username and email are not setup. They are setup though.

What's wrong with my setup?

I set my git config like this:

```
$ git config --global markee.email "mark_e@smith.com"
$ git config --global markee.name "MarkESmith"
```

It checks out:

```
$ git config -l

markee.email=mark_e@smith.com
markee.name=MarkESmith

$ git config --global markee.name
MarkESmith

$ cat ~/.gitconfig

[markee]
    email = mark_e@smith.com
    name = MarkESmith
```

Then I tried to do my putup operation:

```
$ putup boston_housing
ERROR: Make sure git is configured. Run:
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your accounts default identity.
```

Comment: You want `git config --global user.email "mark_e@smith.com"`, etc. That is, `user.email` and `user.name` are literal strings, not something you replace with some other string.

Comment: That solved my problem - and surely in record time. Thank you. That *is* an answer. Perhaps you would register it as one if I rephrase the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```sh
git config --global user.email "mark_e@smith.com"
git config --global user.name "MarkESmith"
```

where the strings are `user.email` and `user.name`, and not parameterized with your username.